# Is there any website I can ask any Question even It's not fully related to Islam but have something to do with Islam

Tags: discussion

I want to ask is there is any website where I can ask any Question even It's not fully related to Islam but has something to do with Islam? Or any discussion website where only Muslims are allowed and can give their opinion  , I want to ask Question about a theory I saw in "Wikipedia talk section"about rise of Islam but I see It's not a place for these type of Question so I want to ask where can I ask these type of Question, I don't want to Question in Quora cause Non Muslims will say garbage and I will lose my iman in these process.

Comment: If you have discord, you can join some Muslim discord servers.

Answer (score 0):

If your iman is that weak, your best bet is to find Muslims in your local community rather than trusting the Internet; it's unlikely that there's any public sites out there that can *effectively* prevent non-Muslims from participating. Even the main Islam.SE Q&A site is only as reliable as community voting allows, and shouldn't be taken as authoritative.

That said, our [Islam.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=islam.stackexchange.com) is available to discuss any topic of interest to the community who have earned [sufficient reputation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). As above I must emphasise that it is available to *all* Stack Exchange users, regardless of religion; while there is no way to limit it only to Muslim participants, we *do* expect everyone to adhere to our [code of conduct](https://islam.stackexchange.com/conduct).